# How to refer to sheet 1 in the document instead of the sheet name? VLOOKUP

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following vlookup in my code, but the tab 'ASN since 12.1.20 w FO' won't always be named that. However, it will always be the first tab in the workbook. How would I refer to tab/worksheet 1 instead of the name of the tab?

```
"=VLOOKUP(RC[-6],'ASN since 12.1.20 w FO'!C[-7]:C[9],17,FALSE)&"",""&TEXT(VLOOKUP(RC[-6],'ASN since 12.1.20 w FO'!C[-7]:C[9],14,),""MM/DD/YYYY"")"
```

Comment: change `'ASN since 12.1.20 w FO'` to `'" & ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Name & "'`

Comment: This prompts a box to select another file, doesn't the This Workbook part mean that it should look into the current workbook?

Comment: `ThisWorkbook` means it look in the workbook in which the code is run.

Comment: If that is not the correct workbook then you need to specify the workbook. `WorkBooks("MyName")`

Comment: If I have the macro saved into a different workbook than the workbook with all of the data, would that be the reason for the error?

Comment: Yes.  You will need to adjust `ThisWorkbook` to refer to the correct workbook.

Answer (score 0):

### 'Build' a Formula in VBA

- When 'building' fairly complicated formulas, it is a good idea to create a procedure to do just that. Every now and then you run it, until you're satisfied with the result.
- If you prefer, you can use a message box instead of `Debug.Print`.

---

```
Option Explicit

Sub FormulaBuilder()
    Dim wsName As String: wsName = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Name
    Dim strFormula As String
    strFormula = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-6],'" & wsName _
        & "'!C[-7]:C[9],17,FALSE)&"",""&TEXT(VLOOKUP(RC[-6],'" & wsName _
        & "'!C[-7]:C[9],14,),""MM/DD/YYYY"")"
    Debug.Print strFormula
    'MsgBox "strFormula"
End Sub
```